# Separate phone & tablet XML layouts not deploying

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-screen-support

I have created 2 XML files where both of which have completely different layouts. Whenever I deploy my app to a phone it loads successfully. However when I do the same thing with a tablet, it doesn't work and therefore crashes. I know that it has something to do with a lack of ListView in the sw600dp layout file but what must be done to make sure that `sw600dp` devices don't keep checking for the ListView?

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**sw600dp/activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/abslistview_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_btn0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_circle"
            android:onClick="btncircle_click"
            android:text="@string/circle"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_btn1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:onClick="btnstar_click"
            android:text="@string/star"
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_btn2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_square"
            android:onClick="btnsquare_click"
            android:text="@string/square"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_btn3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_triangle"
            android:onClick="btntriangle_click"
            android:text="@string/triangle"
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_btn4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_heart"
            android:onClick="btnheart_click"
            android:text="@string/heart"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_btn5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_crescent"
            android:onClick="btncrescent_click"
            android:text="@string/crescent"
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // array of images for ListView
        int[] listviewImage = new int[]{
                R.drawable.ic_circle,
                R.drawable.ic_star,
                R.drawable.ic_square,
                R.drawable.ic_triangle,
                R.drawable.ic_heart,
                R.drawable.ic_crescent
        };

        // array of strings for ListView
        String[] listviewTitle = new String[]{
                getResources().getString(R.string.circle),
                getResources().getString(R.string.star),
                getResources().getString(R.string.square),
                getResources().getString(R.string.triangle),
                getResources().getString(R.string.heart),
                getResources().getString(R.string.crescent)
        };

        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
            hm.put("listview_image", Integer.toString(listviewImage[i]));
            hm.put("listview_title", listviewTitle[i]);
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        String[] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title"};
        int[] to = {R.id.mainitem_img, R.id.mainitem_title};

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listitem_main, from, to);
        ListView list_main = this.findViewById(R.id.listview_main);
        list_main.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        list_main.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    //blah, blah, blah
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                    //blah, blah, blah
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    //blah, blah, blah
                }

                if (position == 3) {
                    //blah, blah, blah
                }

                if (position == 4) {
                    //blah, blah, blah
                }

                if (position == 5) {
                    //blah, blah, blah
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void btncircle_click(View view) {
    }

    public void btnstar_click(View view) {
    }

    public void btnsquare_click(View view) {
    }

    public void btntriangle_click(View view) {
    }

    public void btnheart_click(View view) {
    }

    public void btncrescent_click(View view) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to load your `listview_main` even though in a tablet where that `View` does not exist, so you are getting a NULL value.

This line is giving you a null value in a tablet:

```
ListView list_main = this.findViewById(R.id.listview_main);
```

Because that View is not defined in your tablet layout.

In order to prevent this, you need to control whether you are in a tablet or in a phone. I solved this, creating a resource file inside the `res` folder, and other in your `sw600dp` one.

In the main one you will have this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <bool name="is_tablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

And in the `sw600dp` one:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <bool name="is_tablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Then in your code you need to check whether you are in a tablet or not by doing this:

```
if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet))
```

There you will know what to do according to the loaded layout.

Another option is to have 2 different activities, create a launcher activity that will check your `isTablet` value and then load your `MainActivityPhone` or `MainActivityTablet`.

Hope it helps